# python spark lambda function "nameError: name 'x' is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda

I need to divide the value in one position by the value in another to get the school's acceptance rate.  My lambda function in the last line is causing an issue. I don't understand why `x` needs to be defined if it is within the function.  What can I do to allow me to divide the acceptances by applications?

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("accptRates")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("file:/schoolData.csv")

def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(",")
    name = fields[0]
    private = fields[1]
    apps = int(fields[2])
    accept = int(fields[3])
    return (name, private, apps, accept)

extheader = lines.first() #extract header
header=sc.parallelize([extheader])
schools = lines.subtract(header) #filter out header

rdd = schools.map(parseLine)
private = rdd.filter(lambda x: "Yes" in x[1])
rates = private.map(lambda x: x[0], (x[3]/x[2])).take(10)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/accptRates.py", line 23, in <module>
    rates = private.map(lambda x: x[0], (x[3]/x[2])).take(10)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a lambda function ends when there's a comma, so:

```
private.map(lambda x: x[0], (x[3]/x[2]))
```

is really equivalent to:

```
private.map((lambda x: x[0]), (x[3]/x[2]))
```

which makes the `x` in `x[3]/x[2]` undefined.

If the said lambda function is meant to return a tuple, you should place parentheses around the comma-delimited expressions:

```
private.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[3] / x[2]))
```